# Parsing json post data from dynamic jquery form

Tags: jquery, json, forms, parsing, dynamic

I'm trying to parse JSON data from a jquery form which is dynamically created.  Users can click the "add step" button to add as many (or as few) form fields as they like (including attaching media links), but I have no idea how to process such data within PHP.  Here's some sample form $_POST data I'm expecting to receive:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array //1, 2, 3, 4 are the position for this particular 'step' on the page
        (
            [Counter] => 1
            [Title] => step one
            [Step] => description
            [Links] => Array
                (
                    [0] => link 1
                    [1] => link 2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Counter] => 2
            [Title] => step two
            [Step] => some kind of description
            [Links] => Array
                (
                    [0] => link 2
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Counter] => 3
            [Title] => step three
            [Step] => description (another one)
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Counter] => 4
            [Title] => Step four
            [Step] => a lame description
            [Links] => Array
                (
                    [0] => link 1
                    [1] => link 2
                )

        )

    [tutorial_name] => tutorial name? jesus?
    [tutorial_description] => some useless description
    [tutorial_toolsused] => waste of a tools used
    [tutorial_keywords] => waste of keywords
)
```

Any idea how I could best go about processing such data (regex, foreach) ? Should I avoid using the post protocol?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's not JSON. It looks like a PHP array created by `json_decode()`.

Comment: yes, sorry, allow me to reiterate, this is the print_r dump of the $_POST variable

Comment: What does the form that creates this data look like? The keys of `$_POST` are the `name` attributes of the inputs, do you really have `name='1[Counter]'`?

Comment: I'll try my best to explain a birds eye view of the code - essentially, each of the dynamically created fields is given a name like "steps[]" or "links[]" and features a data-newinput-id attribute which provides the initial id of the field when it was created to keep the elements together.  Later on, the code combines the initial id with its matching fields and pushes them in an object.  The numbers at the very beginning of the object represent the position of each of the fields as they are sortable within the page. I would post the code but it's to messy and is a temporary solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `is_array()` function in PHP to achieve the solution.

Basically, something like this.

```
foreach($_POST as $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        //process your data here. i.e. the counter, step, links, title
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if, by chance, anyone is interested.  Thanks again!

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            //process your data here. i.e. the counter, step, links, title
            echo $value['Position'] . "<br /><br />";
            echo $value['Counter'] . "<br /><br />";
            echo $value['Title'] . "<br /><br />";
            echo $value['Step'] . "<br /><br />";
            if(isset($value['Links'])){
                if(is_array($value['Links'])){
                    foreach($value['Links'] as $link){
                        echo $link . "<br /><br />";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You won't need to use an inner `is_array()` for `$value['Links']` since you already know it to be an array. :)